# Visual Studio 2013 creating unwanted Designer.cs file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a C# project (quite a big one) which I'm developing in Visual Studio 2013

However, I create a new form, say `MyForm.cs`. This automatically creates `MyForm.Designer.cs` and `MyForm.resx` - which is fair enough.

However, every time I edit the form, it automatically creates, within `MyForm.resx`, another class called `MyForm1.Designer.cs`

This prevents the project from building. I can delete the file and it builds fine, but it keeps getting recreated which is getting quite annoying. Why is it creating this file?

**Edit**
Per Hans Passant's comment, here is what is going on.

Before I make a change to the form:[image]

After I make the change:[image]

The "MyForm1.Designer.cs" is the one causing the problem.

Comment: Does this happen only with this particular project/solution? And do you use any extensions that might come into play here? If so, try starting Visual Studio in safe mode using `devenv.exe /SafeMode`.

Comment: You probably duplicated object definitions in the designer file that is in your application code.  I occasionally have to remove the duplicate code from the designer file.  I prefer to put some of the registering of event in my application code and sometimes the end up also in the designer file.  I wouldn't delete the designer file, instead remove the definitions that are duplicated in your code.

Comment: A .resx file contains XML, not a "file".  Hard to guess what you are talking about.  Show us *something* to look at.